# splicing ac adaptor cord which is positive and which is negative?

Tags: power, ac, soldering, wire, adapter

i lost my original asus router power adaptor. so i have a 12v power adaptor with a tip that fits my 19v asus wifi router, and i have a old 19v power adaptor that has a tip that is too small to fit my asus router. so my plan is to cut the tip off the 12v and splice it into the 19v power adaptor so that i have a 19v power adaptor that fits my asus router.

firstly i cut the 12v power adaptor tip with some wire left over but then i couldnt figure out which wire was + - or whatever. I did notice on the ac adaptor power cord that one was black and one had white/grey dashes on it so i broke open the power adaptor and i noticed the wire that had the just black sleeve seems to connect to the + on the board and the wire with the dashes on it connected to the other one. so i assume the black is postivie and the dashes one is negative/ground

when i cut the tip off of the 19v power adaptor, it was different. it had a wire in the middle and then had another wire all around kinda acting like a shield. so now i dont know out of these ones which is positive or negative. i cant crack open the 19v power adaptor and trace cuz i dont wanna end up breaking it.

so how does this work? is the shielding one negative and the middle one is positive? if so then i can just connect it to the other + and - and be good to go. or does it matter what the pin polarity is on the tip?

i attached some pics

any help would be appreciated.

here are pics

Pics of wires
https://i.stack.imgur.com/7IrDT.jpg

Comment: why did you break open the adapter?... why did you not measure the voltage instead?

Comment: I'd suggest getting a cheap-as-chips multimeter and check the polarity of the adapter and the connections on the plug. I assume the router tells you which pin is positive with a little diagram?

Answer (score 2):

Most likely the center core of the round cable is positive and the shield is negative but I would test with a multimeter to be sure.

Answer (score -1):

The coated one in the middle is hot and the One most likely to be exposed in a mishap is negative the hot is better protected so an accidental electrocution is less likely.

Comment: How is electrocution possible on an isolated supply? What difference does it make whether positive or negative ground is used? Welcome to EE.SE but you can't just make stuff up.